# Multimap - wondering about .erase() function

Tags: c++, multimap, erase

I'm practicing my multimaps by looking over examples and existing exercises and I'm pretty confused right now. Can anyone tell me what is being erased here by the myMap.erase(iter->second) here?

```
multimap<int, int> myMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 2)
        myMap.insert(make_pair(i + 1, i * 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2)
        myMap.insert(make_pair(i, i + 2));

multimap<int, int>::iterator iter = myMap.begin();
    ++iter;
    ++iter;
    myMap.erase(iter->second);
    ++iter;

    cout << iter->first << iter->second << endl;
```

So far I know that the multiset is (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 6). However, when I tried to print out pairs at other possible iterator positions, it could no longer print out (4, 6) if I were to increment the iterator there as long as the `myMap.erase(iter->second)` line exists. It gives a map/set iterator not dereferencable error.

What exactly is happening here? What actually got "erased"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map contains elements of a key/value pair.

`erase` is intended to erase from the container a specified key. However, by passing `iter->second` you're passing the third element's value to `erase`, namely 4.

So the element with the key of 4 is deleted which is the last element. If you then try dereference that element with another `++iter` it can't be done, so you get that assertion.

---

Further clarification after comment.

1. At time of calling erase, `iter` is at the (2,4) element.
2. You then call `erase` with parameter 4
3. `erase` looks for an element with key 4 and finds element (4,6) and removes that from the container
4. (nothing to do with 4th element, that's coincidental)

Comment: So it literally takes the 4 in (3, 4), and then erases the "4"th element aka (4, 6)? If the iterator was on (3, 2) when it erases iter->second then it would have erased the 2nd element which is (1, 0)?

Comment: Ah so the key is the first element of the pair. I tried erasing something else and it matches up with this. Thanks for the help!